# Number of satisfying assignments for a propositional clause

Tags: combinatorics, logic

How can I solve these combinatorics problems:

> Given a propositional logic clause $\phi = l_1 \lor \cdots \lor l_l$ where $l_i$ are literals. How many assignments are there for these literals and only these that satisfy the clause?

Also, if we consider the same problem with a bound $k$ for the number of literals in the clause, what would be the solution then?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about disjunctive clauses. Taking your question literally and assuming, as customary, that the language has countably many atoms, it follows that there infinitely many assignments that satisfy the clause. Suppose the atom $p$ is in the literal $l$ and the literal $l$ is in the clause $C$. There are countably many assignments that makes $l$ true and disagree on atoms different from $p$. E.g., let $l=p$. All the assignments that makes $p$ true also makes $C$ true. There are countably many such assignments. Is this all you want to now or there are more requirements?

Comment: @orient thanks for your comment. I assume that you find infinitely many assignments if you consider literals that are not in the formula...am i right? my question wanted to address the assignments to literals that appear in the formula. i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean: suppose that the atoms in $\phi=l_1\lor\dots\lor l_n$ are all the atoms in the language. How many assignments satisfy $\phi$?

If this is your question, then the answer is: $2^n-1$, i.e. all the assignments except the unique one that makes all literals in $\phi$ false.